# number of ways can you climb if u use either 1 or 2 at a time

Tags: algorithm

I faced an interview and was asked the following question :

Given n stairs, how many number of ways can you climb if u use either 1 or 2 at a time?

I think recursion might be useful?.. Is there any other method?

Comment: Indeed. Recursion is a good approach for this problem. As you know, every recursive method can be written as a non-recursive one. (For this specific problem, this can be achieved by some temp variables and loops - Think about it).

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough information to get a good answer. Also, this is not really a "programming" question. You might find better answers on a different Stack Exchange site, like [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/). For future reference, you're also much more likely to get a positive reaction to your question if you use proper spelling and grammar. If you want people to take the time to answer your question thoughtfully, you should take the time to ask your question thoughtfully.

Comment: The more interesting problem is that this looks solvable with a single equation. Consider factorials and triangular numbers.

Comment: How is this related to C? The problem is language agnostic. It has nothing to do with any particular programming language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider L(N) as the number of ways to get to the Nth step.

*Since there are only two steps you can get there from: N-1 and N-2*

All the ways you can get to the step (N-1) + the number of ways to get to the step (N-2) will give you the total number of ways:

L(n) = L(n-1) + L(n-2)

And this looks like **Fibonacci Sequence!**

Comment: Elegant. But this whole question probably belongs on math exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming 
Code:

```
int ways(int n) {
int[] dp = new int[n+1];
Arrays.fill(dp, -1);
return go(0, dp, n); 
}

int go(int step, int[] dp, n) {
if(step == n) {
    return 1;
} else if(step>n) {
    return 0;
} else if(dp[step] != -1) {
    return dp[step];
} else {`enter code here`
    int ways = go(step+1, dp, n) + go(step+2, dp, n);
    dp[step] = ways;
    return ways; 
}
}
```

Comment: This is amazingly inefficient considering this has already been shown to be a fibonacci sequence. It can be solved with a single equation: `floor( pow( 0.5 + SQRT5 * 0.5, (double) n ) / SQRT5 + 0.5 )` (with `SQRT5` defined appropriately)